# Cannot place files and shortcut on my desktop

Tags: shortcut-keys, icons

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.10. Although someone said that it is not possible to upgrade from 18.10 to 20.04 I distinctly remember upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10.  I upgraded to 20.04 following the online instructions on how to do it through the command line.  Now that the upgrade is done I can no longer place files or shortcut on my desktop.  Many images in the various sites describing the new OS shows such icons as the recycle bin on the desktop but I don't even have that.  The files I had on the desktop before the upgrade show in the Desktop folder but that is it.  After the upgrade I noticed that I only had two gnome extensions and none of them had to do with the desktop icons so, again following online instructions, I added the rest of the missing gnome extensions but again there are no extensions dealing with desktop icons.

Can anyone help me in how to return those files to my desktop.  I am not 100% proficient with Ubuntu yet as I was a Microsoft weenie and only recently switched to Linux so I may need a bit of step by step instructions.

Comment: You mean, from 19.10? An upgrade directly from 18.10 would not be possible. Please correct by editing your answer. If really 18.10, then indicate also the procedure you used for doing the upgrade.

Comment: Performing `ls /home/(your username)/Desktop` produces what? In the desktop appearance, there are different modes; for example "Layout: Desktop" does not show your files.

Comment: Things are different in 19.xx and 20.xx... in that desktop icons don't work the same... as much as that fact pains everybody. First, either go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, or use GNOME Tweaks, and enable Desktop Icons, and in the settings, enable the two possible icons that it supports. Then, to move files/icons to/from the Desktop, you need to have two open Nautilus windows, and drag files/icons between the open windows.

Comment: When I use the ls /home/(my name)/Desktop, my files are showing in the folder.

Comment: heynnema.  That fixed my problem.  Thank you.